# magento 2: js function not working from template file

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I have created a js file in my custom module: `components.js` which contains the following code:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($) {
    function checkFormValues(inputs, radio) {
        var empty = false;
        $(inputs).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    $.each(radio, function(index, value) {
        if (!$("input[name='" + value + "']:checked").val()) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    return empty;
}

function checkEnableSubmit(inputs, radio, button) {
    if (checkFormValues(inputs, radio)) {
        $(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $(button).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
});
```

I am then requiring the js file in my template file via requirejs and referencing the functions, however the console outputs error

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'ms.ux'
], function($, ui, ux) {
    checkEnableSubmit('.form-service-plan input', ['plan_code', 'is_scb'], '.js-submit');
    $('.form-service-plan input').change(function () {
        checkEnableSubmit('.form-service-plan input', ['plan_code', 'is_scb'], '.js-submit');
    });
});
</script>
```

which outputs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkEnableSubmit is not defined
```

The components.js file is loading fine, so I believe the issue is with js function declarations but am not sure how to resolve.

### Update:

I was able to get functions to work if i removed the requirejs wrapper and change $ to jQuery in components.js.

```
function checkFormValues(inputs, radio) {
    var empty = false;
    jQuery(inputs).each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    jQuery.each(radio, function(index, value) {
        if (!jQuery("input[name='" + value + "']:checked").val()) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    return empty;
}

function checkEnableSubmit(inputs, radio, button) {
    if (checkFormValues(inputs, radio)) {
        jQuery(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        jQuery(button).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

Should I not use requirejs wrapper for any shared functions or libraries?

Comment: Is `ms.ux` referring to `components.js`? If not then you need to add `components.js` as a dependency. One of the positives of Require JS is that your JS is not globally accessible.

Comment: yes, ms.ux is the reference to components.js

Comment: What happens if you replace `checkEnableSubmit` with `ux.checkEnableSubmit`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkEnableSubmit' of undefined.  I also did a `console.log(ux)` which output `undefined`

Comment: One last quick fix attempt, what happens if you change `require` to `define` in `components.js`? I'm thinking that you may need to use `define` to define it as a module.

Comment: yes I changed require to define in component.js and all is now working properly...if you create answer stating solution, I will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are **defining** a module to be reused you need to use **`define`** rather than `require`.

**About `define`**

With define you register a module in require.js that you can then depend on in other module definitions or require statements.

**About `require`**

With require you "just" load/use a module or javascript file that can be loaded by require.js. For examples have a look at the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles).

#### Example

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($) {
    ...
});
```

Should be

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($) {
    ...
});
```